Is TSP known to be co-NP?
The Travelling Salesman Problem is famously known to be NP.
I was wondering if it is also known whether or not it is co-NP (i.e. its complement is NP)?
If it is known a reference would be much appreciated.

As far as I know, NP = co-NP is still an open problem. If the traveling salesman problem, which is NP-complete, were also co-NP, then NP = co-NP. So I assume this is an open problem.

It is not known whether TSP is in co-NP. Some people, perhaps most, believe TSP is not in co-NP. But this seems extremely hard to prove.
